# How to cite a page in subfloat figure

Tags: floats, citing, subfloats

I want to cite a page within a subfigure. The parsing process breaks because tex assumes the page brackets for the page ref `]` are closing the subfloat command. How can I prevent this or how can I correctly cite a page in a subfigure?

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \subfloat[Confusion matrix for multi-class classification. The confusion matrix of a classification with n classes. When considering the class $k$ $(0 \leq k \leq n)$, the four different classification results can be obtained: true positive (green), true negative (orange), false positive (brown), and false negative (red) \citep[p.73]{kruger2016activity}.]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\textwidth]{multiclass-conf-matrix-alt.png}
  \label{fig:mult-mat}}
  \hfill
  \subfloat[Example for a multiclass confusion matrix \citep{baeld:f1}.]
  {\includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{binary_classes-multi-class-1.png}
  \label{fig:mult-ex}}
  \caption{Multiclass confusion matrices.}
  \label{fig:multi-conf-mat}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a `]` inside an optional argument, you can enclose it in curly braces, e.g.,

```
\subfloat[Example for a multiclass confusion matrix {\citep[47]{baeld:f1}}.]
  {\includegraphics[width=0.55\textwidth]{binary_classes-multi-class-1.png}
```

Comment: I didn't know that. Fantastic answer. Thank you. However, the system tells me that I need 3 more minutes to wait until I can accept it.